# Center align owner drawn checkbox in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I have explored CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox method as well as DrawFrameControl method.
But could not find any way to replicate 
CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter.
Please suggest me how can I achieve the same.
Regards,
Anirban

Comment: CheckBoxRenderer was not made to render a .NET CheckBox control.  It uses the native OS visual styles theme to emulate the way the OS would display a checkbox.  But the .NET CheckBox class does not use the OS version at all, it is a "pure" .NET class.  With lots of added bells and whistles, like the CheckAlign property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So isn't there any way to center align the checkbox ? I am ready to use DrawFrameControl; my intention is to show the checkbox in the center; I

Comment: And the text? Where should the text be positioned? You can perform most of the elements positioning combining the `TextAlign` and `CheckAlign` properties. i.e. `CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter` and `TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter`. Or anything else that fits.

Comment: Hi, I am referring to owner drawing of checkbox using Drawframecontrol, this would not work